# how to get default order status for invoice

Tags: order-status

i am creating a module and i need the default **order status** for invoice.
i know the default status is processing but i don't want to hard code it.
i am already creating the invoice but the order status is not changing.
how can i get that any help will be appreciated.

this is how i generate **invoice**

```
 $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
     try {
           if(!$order->canInvoice())
           {
              $error=true;
              $ids[]=$order->getIncrementId();
           }else {

           $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();

           if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
           Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
           }

           $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
           $invoice->register();
           $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
           ->addObject($invoice)
           ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

           $transactionSave->save();
           $sucess=true;
           $i++;
           }
        }
     catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {

        }


     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following line, it will change the order to the default `processing` state:

```
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
```

You will have to add a line like this though, it will not change automatically as far as I know.